# slimerjs command doesn't do anything after install

Tags: node.js, casperjs, slimerjs

just tried running "slimerjs hello.js" after installing it via npm or homebrew and of course having a hello.js file.
and it just doesn't do anything except going to a new line.
it does not say command not found so that should mean it is installed somehow.
i'm also trying to run it with casperjs like that "casperjs test someDirectory --engine=slimerjs". also nothing happening.
even slimerjs -v is not showing or doing anything.

anybody have come across that or am i just missing something :/
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set the environment variable:

```
On linux:

    export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/usr/bin/firefox

on Windows

    SET SLIMERJSLAUNCHER="c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

On windows with cygwin

    export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER="/cygdrive/c/program files/mozilla firefox/firefox.exe"

On MacOS

    export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

Ref: http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was due to SlimerJS not supporting the latest version of Firefox (37).

It has been fixed in the [github repo](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs) now so if you want to run it you can clone that repo and add the src path of the cloned slimerjs-folder to your PATH variable.

Uninstall slimerjs from homebrew first though.

Eg (OSX & Sublime):

```
brew uninstall slimerjs
mkdir ~/forked && cd $_
git clone https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs.git
subl ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following line to that file

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/forked/slimerjs/src
```

Comment: realized that it was was actually my own fault cause i hadnt put it properly into the path :(